# Sidekiq VS RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, sidekiq

We are in need of a queuing system in our **Ruby On Rails 4** web application

what are the differences and why would/wouldn't you pick

> Sidekiq over RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite different things with different usage. **Sidekiq** is full-featured solution for job queueing and processing, while **RabbitMQ** is just a message broker where you can build your own stuff upon it.

Comment: It's a lot more than that if you use the right gems and plugins, I don't really want to reproduce the whole article in a comment so here it is https://blog.stanko.io/rabbitmq-is-more-than-a-sidekiq-replacement-b730d8176fb