# What's the difference between RabbitMq and Sidekiq?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, sidekiq

I know the RabbitMq and other Mq are messages queues. And the sidekiq usually use Redis to do a job, I am wondering what is the difference between them if they are all queues.

And what are their usage scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sidekiq VS. RabbitMQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525941/sidekiq-vs-rabbitmq)

Comment: @Rob Yeah, but still can not see what's their best use case. Does that answer mean that mq can turn into a sidekiq, but the sidekiq was born later right? What does sidekiq want to solve?

Comment: @crazy_phage I agree, it is not a duplicate. I would also like an answer, thanks